# Upgrading Docker using APT deletes all images and containers

Tags: ubuntu, shell, apt, docker

The following commands are used in a maintenance script in order to upgrade packages on the Ubuntu system:

```
dpkg --configure -a
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt upgrade -yq -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef"
```

The issue is that upgrading Docker (e.g. 20.10.15 -> 20.10.16) deletes all images and containers. It's effectively a clean installation of the new version. This is a problem, since Rancher integration relies on containers.

How can I upgrade Docker, so that images and containers survive?

Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS | `docker-ce/bionic,now 5:20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-bionic amd64 [installed]`

Comment: You are not using Docker package provided by Debian but most probably by upstream. Debian's own packaged Docker is package `docker.io` and has stable version `20.10.5+dfsg1-1+deb11u1` and testing/usntable is version `20.10.14+dfsg1-1` . So I guess you are referring to upstream packaged  `docker-ce` instead. This does matter when talking about a packaged Docker, because packaging and upgrade management can be quite different.

Comment: Note: `docker.io` had no issue with upgrades, but at the same time there are rarely upgrades (last was in December 2021 for some backported security fixes). And also there is a dedicated Debian package for managing upgrades: `unattended-upgrades`.

Comment: @A.B - The OS is Ubuntu, so not Debian in this case. Who is the “upstream” providing `docker-ce`?  Do you know whether there are problems upgrading this package?

Comment: Is there a way to customise the upgrade, so data persist between releases?

Comment: Ubuntu also provides [docker.io](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/docker.io). I was expecting you'd clarify what you installed and that you'd know what upstream means or is. I don't know how to help further.

Comment: @A.B - Sorry for not meeting your expectations. The Docker package is `docker-ce/bionic,now 5:20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-bionic amd64 [installed]` on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. Regarding *upstream*, I mean *who* is the upstream in this case? Is it Docker, some package maintainers, etc.? I hope you are still able to help.

Comment: @Shuzheng `apt-cache policy docker-ce` should tell you which repos it's available from